# C Turning lines of an archive into arrays

Tags: c, arrays, string, csv, archive

I have an archive and I want to turn every line into an array: v[i].data.
However, when I run the code it shows zeros for the arrays.
Is there anything I should change?

**Input**

> 1760
>   02/20/18,11403.7
>   02/19/18,11225.3
>   02/18/18,10551.8
>   02/17/18,11112.7
>   02/16/18,10233.9

**Actual Output**

> 1761
>       0

**Expected Output**

> 1761
>   02/20/18,11403.7

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>


typedef struct{
    char data[20];

}vetor;

int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
    FILE *csv;

        if((csv=fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL  )
        {
            printf("not found csv\n");
            exit(1);
        }


        long int a=0;

        char linha[256];

        char *token = NULL;

        if(fgets(linha, sizeof(linha), csv)) //counting lines
        {
            token = strtok(linha, "\n");
            a =(1 + atoi(token));
        }


        printf("%d\n", a);

        rewind(csv);

        vetor *v;

        v=(vetor*)malloc(a*sizeof(vetor));

        char linha2[256];

        while (fgets(linha2, sizeof(linha2), csv) != 0)
        {
            fseek(csv, +1, SEEK_CUR);

            for(int i=0;i<a;i++)
            {   
                fscanf(csv, "%[^\n]", v[i].data);


            }
        }

        printf("%s\n", v[0].data);


    fclose(csv);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why the `rewind` and why the `fseek` and why the `fscanf` since you already read sequential lines with `fgets`?

Comment: What's the point of this line? `fseek(csv, +1, SEEK_CUR);`

Comment: You can use `sscanf` to extract the data from `linha`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a number of mistakes so I went ahead and rewrote the problem areas with comments explaining what I did

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct{
    char data[20];

}vetor;

int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
    FILE *csv;

    if((csv=fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL  )
    {
        printf("not found csv\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    char line[20];

    // Read number of lines
    int num_lines = 0;
    if (!fgets(line, sizeof(line), csv)) {
        printf("Cannot read line\n");
        exit(1);    
    }
    char* token = strtok(line, "\n");
    num_lines = atoi(token) + 1;
    vetor* v = malloc(num_lines * sizeof(vetor));

    // Fill in vetor
    int i = 0;
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), csv) != NULL) {
        int len = strlen(line);
        line[len-1] = '\0'; // replace newline with string terminator
        strcpy(v[i].data, line); //copy line into v[i].data
        i++;
    }

    printf("%d\n", num_lines);
    for (i = 0; i < num_lines; i++) {
            printf("%s\n", v[i].data);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I think the main mistake was a misunderstanding of how best to read in each line of information. If I understood correctly you want each `02/20/18,11403.7` line to be an element in the `vetor` array.

The easiest way is to simply get each line one at a time with fgets

```
while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), csv) != NULL)
```

Change the ending character from newline to the string terminating character `'\0'`

```
int len = strlen(line);
line[len-1] = '\0';
```

Then copy the string into the ith element of `vetor` and update `i` for the next iteration of the loop.

```
strcpy(v[i].data, line);
i++;
```

Comment: replace the line `line[len-1] = '\0';` with `line[strcspn(line, "\n")] = 0;`, you want to remove the newline if and only if there is a newline.

Comment: And use `strncpy` instead of `strcpy` otherwise you might overflow `v[i].data`

Comment: You should check that `i` doesn't get to `num_lines`, otherwise you are overflowing the allocated memory.

Comment: @Pablo `strncpy` and `strcspn` are best practice but I was only giving an minimal example to convey the ideas. Not necessarily handling all edge cases.

Comment: *The first line contains the number of lines to be read*  yes, I deleted the comment after I realized that the first line has the total number of lines. I've seen similar questions where the OP reads the whole CSV first in order to calculate the number of lines. That confused me at first and that's why I wrote the comment, then I realized my mistake and removed the comment.

Comment: *Not necessarily handling all edge cases* I don't agree with that, even if it's a "minimal example", code should be correct and using `strcpy` when you don't know the length of the source string, is incorrect. If the size of the source buffer were smaller than `v[i].data`, then that would be OK, but this is not the case.

Comment: Changed length of src buffer to be the same as v[i].data.

Comment: That's OK then.